# Does Cloud Functions read firebase data locally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

If I set up a cloud function that requires getting a lot of info from database or firestore, will it access them locally and be able to quickly process through a LOT of data, or will it request data from the server and act like a regular client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that Cloud Functions could scale massively as it does *and* still read your database locally.  Each server instance that's spun up for your functions is an isolated environment for that function.  If your function accesses Realtime Database or Firestore, it will be doing so over Google's internal networks.

If you have concerns about performance, you should benchmark it according to your expected situation.  No one can make any guesses if it's going to be "fast enough" without some concrete data to work with.

Comment: Ok thanks. As an extra, is it possible then to keep a cloud function always running and have it store the relevant database info, so that whenever it is triggered, it does not have to access database?

Comment: Cloud Functions will scale up as many server instances as needed to handle the load on your function.  Each one of these will start with a blank slate.  You have no control over how Cloud Functions scales up or down, unless you want to manually apply enough load to keep server instances running.  That will just cost you money.  If you have a need to keep a large data set in memory, Cloud Functions may not be the best choice for you.  Consider using App Engine to keep an instance under your control, if that's what you need.